# Would it be beneficial to land Falcon Heavy's side boosters on droneships too?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, falcon-heavy, droneship

Although the synchronous landing of the Falcon Heavy side boosters looks impressive, they seem to have traveled a long way back to the landing zones.

How does this compare with Falcon 9 launches with land landing?

Would it have been more efficient in this case to land the side boosters on additional droneships?

I'm interested in whether the amount of droneships was a bottleneck here, or if the way it was done was actually the best option.

Also, are there any plans known for possible multi-droneship missions?

---

Update:

- Good point by NPSF3000: Elon Musk [has estimated](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/963094533830426624) the costs for landing the side boosters while expending the core to be around \$95M. This comes along with ~10% less performance compared to fully expended, [which would cost $150M](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/963076231921938432).
- [SpaceX is actually building a second droneship on the east coast do do exactly that.](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/963104633639002112) Its name will be *A Shortfall of Gravitas*.

Comment: When Red Dragon was on the schedule, it was going to land the side boosters on droneships and expend the center core. Moot point now, though.

Comment: I'll have to find a source, but Elon musk has mentioned the possibility of center expended, side on barge FH config.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @NPSF3000. I have read this, too, and included the reference in the question.

Comment: Thing is, if the side boosters land in the sea, you kind of have to expand the central core since it'll separate even further away

Comment: Good to hear they are keeping with the naming convention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently SpaceX has only one drone ship in the Atlantic, [*Of Course I Still Love You*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_spaceport_drone_ship#Of_Course_I_Still_Love_You_(Marmac_304)), so it wasn't an option. As far as I know, they aren't planning to build more; their goal is to do as many return-to-launch-site (RTLS) landings as possible in the future.

Landing all three on drone ships would allow them to expend more fuel in boosting, increasing the potential payload of a Falcon Heavy launch, but it would add several days of sea travel to the turnaround time of a booster.